# Remote Notification removing in watchOS

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchos-3

I wonder is it possible to remove a notification from an Apple Watch that was sent by my application?
I really need it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, you just have to call one of the following two methods of UNUserNotificationCenter: `removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:)` or `removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter)